# Dúvida se "após" é uma preposição ou advérbio

Tags: gramática, preposições, advérbios, classe-gramatical

Estava vendo uma lista de preposições, aquelas listas de classificação de palavras para ajudar na compreensão, e "após" apareceu como uma delas. Para mim, foi insensato colocar "após" porque ela SOLTA deveria ser "rotulada" como um advérbio. Estou correto? A lista é para iniciantes.

Estou correto em afirmar abaixo as classes gramaticais?

Cheguei após ele sair. (advérbio)

Cheguei após a chuva. (preposição)

Answer (score 1):

Não é incomum que, na língua portuguesa, um termo tenha mais de uma classificação.

A palavra **após** é um termo que *essencialmente* é classificada como uma preposição. Apesar disso, podemos utilizá-la como um advérbio temporal a depender do contexto.

Podemos classificar o termo *após* como uma preposição quando ele estabelece determinadas relações de sentido ou quando for equivalente à locução prepositiva (*depois de*)

> Lembre-se: Aconteça o que acontecer, nada como um dia *após (= depois de)* outro dia
>   
>   Cheguei *após (= depois de)* ele sair.
>   
>   Cheguei *após (= depois da)* chuva.

Já como advérbio, é necessário que o termo modifique o advérbio, o adjetivo ou o verbo, desde que não seja complementado por uma expressão nominal. Poderá ser substituído por *depois* ou *em seguida*.

> Ela tomou coragem e, logo *após (= em seguida)*, se deu conta de quão forte ela era.

<sup>Fontes:

[Só Português](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf81.php)

[Ciber Dúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-classe-morfossintatica-de-apos/32158)

[Fernando Pestana](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=IxomyAEACAAJ&dq=Fernando+Pestana&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjljdLp59XlAhWXK7kGHRAjAKgQ6AEIKTAA)</sup>